# How do you access PostGIS geometry data from .NET

Tags: postgis, c#, .net

I have a PostgreSQL / PostGIS database with both geometry and non spatial columns

I created a new Console App .Net framework project  and added these nuget packages

EntityFramework
pgsql
EntityFramework6.npgsql
Npgsql.NetTopologySuite

When I create a database first ADO.net data Entity Modal I can see the  non spatial columns but not the geometry see pics

Could someone explain what I need to enable spatial queries?

[image: PostgreSQL / PostGIS table (note last column is geometry)]

[image: EF Data Model note Geometry column is missing]

Comment: You should write a WKT query. Do you know about its use with EF?